# Class inheritance is not found

Tags: php, class, zend-framework, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I am building an application using Zend Framework and Doctrine 2.

My code looks like this:

```
namespace Entities;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** 
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\Person") 
 * @Table(name="persons")
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"2"="User"})
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

And my class User

```
namespace Entities;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** 
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\User") 
 */
class User extends Person
{

}
```

Now,  I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Entities\Person' not found in C:\xamp\htdocs\Persons\application\m
odels\Entities\User.php on line 13
```

I have no idea why I get that error. I have tried calling the "Person" class in many different ways but the its not working. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in Zend Framework, you have an autoloader setup that handles the loading of classes for you dynamically.

When you run just the Doctrine tool from the command line, you don't have an autoloader at your disposal. Doctrine is trying to load the User class, which requires Person, and yet it doesn't (apparently) know how to load Person.

I think the simple solution would be to have `require_once('Person.php');` at the top of your User entity. This is probably unnecessary for ZF, but will be helpful for Doctrine command line tools.

Comment: Hi. I actually changed my question because I noticed that it doesnt happen only when I'm trying to update with Doctrine, but it's also happening with framework. Maybe a problem with my autoloader?

Comment: Seems like it, yes. Have you tried sticking the require_once at the top anyway? It might still be the easiest way to solve both issues.

Comment: wouldn't that be an overkill though? I'll try it

Comment: I'm assuming your Person class really is located at models\Entities\Person.php?

Comment: Ok. I see. My problem was that I was doing extends \Person, that's why it wasnt working in the Framework, when I made it extends Person it worked in framework but not in update. I'll guess I'll do require_once and comment it out after I use the tool. Thanks!